# ADODB Connection to two access database

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, adodb

Due to ms access 2GB limitations on space;
i am considering splitting a database into two.

However I regularly rely on SQL statements such as the following:

```
INSERT INTO [...] SELECT [...]
```

Is there a way in ADODB to perform the above, ie INSERT INTO table in file 1,
the SELECT data from a table in file 2 ?

Comment: Maybe it's time to consider a better RDMS? SQL Server Express, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example of updating one accdb from another using VBA and ADO:

```
Sub AddDataFromAccessToAccess()
   Dim cn                As Object
   Dim sDatabase As String
   Dim sDatabase2 As String

   ' change these paths
   sDatabase = "C:\Database1.accdb"
   sDatabase2 = "C:\Database2.accdb"

   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   With cn
      .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source='" & sDatabase & "'"
      .Open
      ' change table and field names here
      .Execute "INSERT INTO Table1 ([Field1]) SELECT [Field2] FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=" & sDatabase2 & ";].[Table2]"
      .Close
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Rory!! It works perfectly with one field but when i add more fields i get a Run-Time Error: Syntax Error (comma) in query expression. My statement:    "INSERT INTO Temp_Fees (Account, TradeDate, Description) SELECT (Account, TradeDate, Description) FROM [MS Access; DATABASE=" & sDatabase2 &  ";].Temp_Fees"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting your db to CurrentDB, use OpenDatabase.

```
eg.
    set DB = opendatabase("fkdslfjslj")
```

Comment: But, if you "split" the database then you would have linked tables to the other database, so you would just refer to the (linked) tables as per normal.

Comment: Table links between the two back-end files would be a much tidier solution. Perhaps you could add that suggestion to your answer?

Comment: @GordThompson I realized after posting that he was talking about "split" so I added comment about table links.